# Printing F# discriminated union

Tags: f#, mono, tostring, discriminated-union

I am writing a F# program which parses a string into a AST type which is a discriminated union.

When I use `fsi` (on Mono + Mac OS X) to run my code, the AST is printed out in a nice format. But when I use `printfn "%s" <| ast.ToString()` I get something like `FSI_0002.Absyn+clazz`. Writing a `ToString` method for all the discriminated union types would be a big chore.

How do I make the value print the way `fsi` does it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259039/what-is-the-enum-getname-equivalent-for-f-union-member

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried `printfn "%A" ast`? The `%A` specifier takes into consideration the [`StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute`<sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370334.aspx), if present.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a discriminated union into a string, you should use `sprintf "%A" ast` instead of ast.ToString().

If you want [Enum.GetName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx), you can use `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` namespace. See [What is the Enum.GetName equivalent for F# union member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259039/what-is-the-enum-getname-equivalent-for-f-union-member).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Daniel's comment, here is a good blog article explaining how to format it in whatever way you'd wish:

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/08/some-tips-and-tricks-for-formatting-data-in-f-interactive-and-a-in-sprintf-printf-fprintf.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20151011213338/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/08/some-tips-and-tricks-for-formatting-data-in-f-interactive-and-a-in-sprintf-printf-fprintf.aspx) (web.archive.org)

Comment: This link is archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20151011213338/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/08/some-tips-and-tricks-for-formatting-data-in-f-interactive-and-a-in-sprintf-printf-fprintf.aspx