# Pretty Printing in Deedle Data Frame

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, deedle

I was wondering if there is a simple way to add pretty printing to a custom type used in a Deedle data frame.

In the following example:

```
open Deedle

type PrimaryContactInfo =
    | Default of int
    | NonDefault of int
    | Missing

type Account = { PrimaryContact : PrimaryContactInfo }

[ { PrimaryContact = Default(1) }; { PrimaryContact = Default(2) }; { PrimaryContact = NonDefault(5) } ]
|> Frame.ofRecords
```

I get the following output in fsi:

```
     PrimaryContact                         
0 -> FSI_0011+PrimaryContactInfo+Default    
1 -> FSI_0011+PrimaryContactInfo+Default    
2 -> FSI_0011+PrimaryContactInfo+NonDefault
```

but I would rather have output like this:

```
     PrimaryContact                         
0 -> Default(1)    
1 -> Default(2)   
2 -> NonDefault(5)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7452074/126014

Comment: See also https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/7574961-override-tostring-for-discriminated-unions-and-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As implied by [this language feature suggestion](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/7574961-override-tostring-for-discriminated-unions-and-r), F# discriminated unions don't automatically convert nicely to strings.

You can make it convert nicely by overriding `ToString`:

```
type PrimaryContactInfo =
    | Default of int
    | NonDefault of int
    | Missing
    override this.ToString () = sprintf "%A" this
```

Notice, however, that the use of `"%A"` may be **slow**, so measure, and write a faster, more explicit implementation if necessary; for example:

```
type PrimaryContactInfo =
    | Default of int
    | NonDefault of int
    | Missing
    override this.ToString () =
        match this with
        | Default i -> sprintf "Default %i" i
        | NonDefault i -> sprintf "NonDefault %i" i
        | Missing -> "Missing"
```

This produces exactly the same output as `sprintf "%A`, but doesn't use Reflection, so should, *in theory*, be faster (but don't take my word on it: **measure**).