# Discriminated union member methods

Tags: inheritance, f#, discriminated-union

I want to define a method shared by all members of a discriminated union.  Currently I've implemented it like this, but it seems really inelegant- surely there is a better way. Suggestions?

```
type A = 
   {AData:string}
   member this.SharedMethod (x:float) : int= ...
type B =
   {BData:float}
   member this.SharedMethod (x:float) : int= ...
type AB =
| A of A
| B of B

let CallSharedMethod (ab:AB) x =
   match ab with
   | AB.A(a') -> a'.SharedMethod x
   | AB.B(b') -> b'.SharedMethod x
```

Comment: You are missing the instance binding, i.e.: this.SharedMethod otherwise it will not work. Also you need to add more information about what does your shared method with the instance of the DU (in fact is a record type), because if it does nothing you can use a regular function. I'm sure is not your case.

Comment: Smells to me like the method should be on the DU. But if not, you can use records to implement an interface.

Comment: Yes, sorry my code was not exactly syntactically correct. I'm more interested in the pattern- how do I denote the fact that every subtype of the DU share a common method name?  I'll edit the code to make it more correct.

Comment: Ok, I can make CallSharedMethod a method of AB. But I still have to do the pattern match.  Your other suggestion- making the record an interface seems like the best option.  I'll try this.

Comment: That will still require matching to get at the case fields. The only other option is reflection, or classes.

Comment: If you want every case of a DU to act the same you're not discriminating. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
type AB =
    | A of string
    | B of float

    member self.SharedMethod (x : float) =
        match self with
        | A s -> x
        | B f -> f + x
```

This assumes that you want each variant of your sum type (aka discriminated union) to do something different with the float parameter.

For the case of `A`, I just return the original value since there's not much else I can do (since there is no generally useful relationship between `string` and `float` that yields a `float`).

Answer (score 9):

In your example, you have *augmented* the *record* types `A` and `B` each with an instance member. However, you can not only augment record types, you can also augment *union* types (as shown in @Rodrick's answer). If you do this, the union's augmentation will be "shared" by each DU case, which is what you have asked for. To make this more explicit, I have renamed some parts of your example:

```
type A = { AData:string }
type B = { BData:float }

type AB =
    | ACase of A
    | BCase of B
    member __.SharedMethod x = 0

let callSharedMethod (ab:AB) x = ab.SharedMethod x
```

If you look at the compiled code in the object browser (or a decompiler like ILSpy), you will see that `AB` is compiled as the base class of two subclasses `AB.ACase` and `AB.BCase`, and `SharedMethod` belongs to the base class `AB`.

See also section 8.5.1 of the [F# 3.0 specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf): Members in Union Types.