# Fable/F# - How do I save enums or discriminated unions to the browser?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I can save a string to local browser storage with

`Browser.localStorage.setItem(key, str)`

but when I try to stringify a discriminated union (e.g. by calling `string` on it), it comes out as `[Object object]`.

Since the [`FSharp.Reflection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259039/what-is-the-enum-getname-equivalent-for-f-union-member) and enum-manipulation functions are not supported in Fable, how can I save and load a DU or enum value (without doing a bunch of extra work for every case)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [Fable docs](http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html), you can use the function `Fable.Import.JS.JSON.stringify` to serialize the DU, and `Fable.Import.JS.JSON.parse` to deserialize it. This allows it to be saved and loaded from browser localStorage.

There is also a `[<StringEnum>]` attribute, which I assume makes enums be treated as their string representation, but I did not test it for this use case.